# Show only directories, not their contents with `find -type d | xargs ls`

Tags: linux, shell, find, ls, xargs

I want to find some folders by name, and then list their information using "ls", here is what i did using "find",

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name logs
```

what i got is:

```
./RECHMN32Z/US/logs
./RECHMN32Z/UM/logs
./RECHMP3BL/US/logs
./RECHMP3BL/UM/logs
./RECHMAS86/UM/logs
./RECHMAS86/US/logs
```

and then i add "xargs ls -l" , then it will return information of all files under these folders returned above,
if i just want to list information of these folders, how to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not find or xargs's fault, but ls's. When given directory names ls shows their contents. You can use `-d` to have it only show the directories themselves.

find has a `-ls` action that uses the same format as `ls -dils`. No need to invoke an external command.

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name logs -ls
```

Or use `ls -ld` to list the directories and not their contents. `-exec cmd {} +` is a simpler alternative to `xargs`. No pipeline required.

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name logs -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Comment: the format of result of "find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name logs -ls" is not readable, and "find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name logs -exec ls -ld {} +" is perfect, and meet my expectation, thanks,